# Unable to add a service to IBM Watson Studio

Tags: ibm-cloud, instance, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I cannot create a project in IBM Watson Studio for an online course (sponsored by IBM by the way). I keep getting this error:

**"You can only have one instance of a Lite plan per service. To create a new instance, either delete your existing Lite plan instance or select a paid plan".**

I am performing the following steps:

```
1.Watson Studio
2.Create (Lite Plan Option)
3.Get Started
4.Create Project
5.Create Empty Project
6.Select Storage Service --> Here I get the error message
```

I need to create a Jupyter Notebook in IBM Watson Studio in order to complete the course.

I've deleted the Watson instance and started from scratch several times. I have also created a new account and tried the solutions posted on this forum for similar cases, without success.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have Lite account on IBM Cloud and here's the limitation with the account type

> You can provision one instance of any service in the IBM Cloud catalog
>   that has a Lite plan.

You can check What's available with your Lite account of IBM Cloud [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-accounts#lite-account-features).

You may have to delete the other service provisioned under Lite plan before creating the Cloud Object Storage service or you can choose the `Standard` plan of Cloud Object storage service.

To check the Lite services which you already created in your account, navigate to [Resource list](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources). You may have to delete